# PhantomJs screen master not saving images but output files

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ubuntu, phantomjs

I just installed PhantomJs and followed the [instructions](https://github.com/microweber/screen) for the PHP Screen capture

but when i load the

```
shot.php?url=google.com
```

all i get is a file inside the `jobs` folder that contains this code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 768};

page.open('http://google.com', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }


    page.evaluate(function() {
                    /* This will set the page background color */
            if (document && document.body) {
                document.body.bgColor = '#FFFFFF';
            }

            });

    setTimeout(function() {
            page.render('test.jpg');
            phantom.exit();
    }, 0);
});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change timeout time?

Comment: The lib prob just generates code for phantom js to execute, hence `jobs`.

Comment: @observer no i havent, but they don't mention editing those files...

Comment: @LawrenceCheron oh you mean jobs folder are queued jobs to be done? but then how do i execute them? the documentation on github is poor, the dont mention anything about it

Comment: Actually looking at the code it should be calling the binary and running the script https://github.com/microweber/screen/blob/af7652bc9b3b50406903ebe8d5833d6893d9e884/src/Capture.php#L256 You might want to go into the vendor dir and debug it abit to see why its not firing, it could be a few things.

Comment: Check `$this->binPath` is correct and that its got the execute bit.

Comment: And wrap the code, especially `$screen->save($fileLocation);` in try catch..

Answer (score 0):

ok first thing, you need to replace the phantomJs file inside the `screen-master/bin`
because is apparently outdated...

second instead of their demo i used this PHP code that is much simpler

```
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) {
    exit;
}

require_once '../autoload.php';
use Screen\Capture;

$screen = new Capture($_GET['url']);
$screen->setImageType('png');

$t = time();
$t = date("Ymdhi", $t);

$filename = md5($_GET['url']);

$temp_dir = '/var/www/yoursite/screen-master/jobs/test/' . $filename . $t . '_1';
$screen->setWidth(370);
$screen->save($temp_dir);
```

the location dir, yes it is absolute server path, not relative